# Why Scala playframework doesn't import library

Tags: scala, testing, playframework

I'm trying to use [this tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest). But I got stuck while trying to import library

```
import org.scalatestplus.play._
```

I added this dependency in my build.sbt

```
  libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus" % "play_2.10" % "1.2.0"
```

It doesn't update dependency list.

If I try activator update I succeed as

```
$ activator update

[info] Loading project definition from /Users/masum/work/app/project
[info] Set current project to app (in build file:/Users/masum/work/app/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/masum/work/app/}root...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatestplus/play_2.11/1.2.0/play_2.11-1.2.0.jar ...
  [info]    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalatestplus#play_2.11;1.2.0!play_2.11.jar (1253ms)
  [info] Done updating.
  [success] Total time: 6 s, completed Mar 3, 2015 5:50:21 PM
```

Even after that I can't

```
   import org.scalatestplus.play._
```

Here is my build.sbt:-

```
  lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

  scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

  libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus" % "play_2.11" % "1.2.0" % "test"

 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 jdbc,
 anorm,
 cache,
 ws,
 "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.11" % "3.0.0-M1",
 "com.typesafe.play" % "play-slick_2.11" % "0.8.1",
 "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
 "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1200-jdbc41",
 "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test",
 "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.10.19" % "test",
 "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.166",
 "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.6.20",
 "org.scala-lang" % "scala-actors" % "2.11.0"
 )
```

What is wrong? How to import org.scalatestplus.play._

## Update with more information with test code

```
  class StackSpec extends PlaySpec {

    "A Stack" must {
      "pop values in last-in-first-out order" in {
        val stack = new Stack[Int]
        stack.push(1)
        stack.push(2)
        stack.pop() mustBe 2
        stack.pop() mustBe 1
      }
      "throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped" in {
        val emptyStack = new Stack[Int]
        a [NoSuchElementException] must be thrownBy {
          emptyStack.pop()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: any specific reason for adding test dependency seperately?

Comment: Where are you trying to perform the import? REPL, src/main, or src/test?

Comment: What is the actual error thrown? What happens when you compile your tests by `test:compile`?

Comment: @singhakash I was trying inside Seq(..) and outside both way has same result. Just while asking question it remain outside.

Comment: @JustinPihony I'm trying in a Play 2.0 web application. So it is in app/test/ directory

Comment: Are you seeing errors in Idea/Eclipse, or while compiling.. ?

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari While I compile from console by  test:compile. I get error as :- test:compile
[info] Compiling 3 Scala sources to /Users/masum/work/app/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[error] /Users/masum/work/app/test/NewTest.scala:69: not found: type PlaySpec
[error] class StackSpec extends PlaySpec {
[error]                         ^
[error] /Users/masum/work/app/test/NewTest.scala:71: value must is not a member of String
[error]   "A Stack" must {
[error]             ^
[error] /Users/masum/work/app/test/NewTest.scala:72: value in is not a

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh While I compile from console by  test:compile. I get error as :- test:compile
[info] Compiling 3 Scala sources to /Users/masum/work/app/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[error] /Users/masum/work/app/test/NewTest.scala:69: not found: type PlaySpec
[error] class StackSpec extends PlaySpec {
[error]                         ^
[error] /Users/masum/work/app/test/NewTest.scala:71: value must is not a member of String
[error]   "A Stack" must {
[error]             ^
[error] /Users/masum/work/app/test/NewTest.scala:72: value in is not a member of String
 Also form Idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there were issue in scalatestplus-play. Check @

https://github.com/scalatest/scalatestplus-play/issues/15

I worked for me while use

```
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.2.0" % "test"
```

Thanks to all who tried to support me.